# Do these two sentences mean the same?

Tags: sentence-meaning, comparison

Do these two sentences mean the same?

> Knowing that I hurt you is breaking my heart.

And

> If I know I hurt you, it is breaking my heart.

Comment: *It is* is a declarative statement.  It can't be used after *if*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is not grammatically correct, and thus doesn't really mean anything.

It could be made grammatically correct by changing to

> I know I hurt you, and it is breaking my heart.

which would mean the same thing as the first, as dropping the if makes it a declarative statement, not a conditional.

If you changed it to

> If I *knew* I hurt you, it *would* break my heart

now it is a conditional (you don't know you hurt them, but if you did, it would break your heart) and it doesn't mean the same as the original.